# Air Resistance of a Falling Object

Tags: physics, euler-method

I am applying air resistance to a falling sphere using the Euler method. If someone could have a look and tell me if my implementation is correct or offer any tips, it would be highly appreciated.

Calculations taken from [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29)

```
float Mass = 10;
float Radius = 5;
Vector Gravity = Vector(0, 9.8, 0)

float p = 1.293f;              // Air Density;
float A = pow(Radius, 2) * PI; // Cross Section Area;
float Cd = 0.47f;              // Drag Coefficient For Sphere;

float terminalVelocity = sqrt(2 * Mass * Gravity.magnitude / p * A * Cd);

// Update

Vector acceleration = Gravity * ( 1 / Mass);

m_velocity += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;

float drag = 0.5f * p * pow(m_velocity.magnitude, 2f) * Cd * A;

m_velocity -= new Vector3 (0, clamp(drag, 0, terminalVelocity), 0);

m_position += m_velocity * Time.deltaTime;
```

Cheers

Comment: Please describe the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: The OP is performing the "semi-implicit" Euler integration but might have misunderstood how to implement drag: that drag effect comes from a _force_ and should be incorporated in the acceleration by dividing the _drag force_ by the mass of the object. I recommend a predictor-corrector approach, but the OP should also look into implicit integrators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method since the update is implicit anyways (the velocity update is a function of velocity itself).

Comment: Gravity is the acceleration, not the force; the gravitational _force_ is `gm`, where `m` is the mass of the object and `g` is the gravitational constant. Expanding on what @teodron is describing, you're calculating gravity at `v(t)`, but the drag force at `v(t + dt)`. You should calculate the net force at time `t`, which is `f(t) = gm - d(t)` where `d` is the drag force function. Then update your velocity via `v(t + dt) = (f(t)/m) * dt`. Your position update is correct. Lastly note that terminal velocity arises naturally, you don't _necessarily_ need to enforce it.

Comment: That should be `v(t + dt) = v(t) + (f(t)/m) * dt`.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. I have updated my logic as suggested, but when using the equation from wikipedia (0.5 * p * vel^2 * Cd * A) my velocity goes out of control. I am having trouble understanding how the terminal velocity arises naturally. Any chance you could include an answer with the wiki drag equation.

Comment: Add an edit to your question with the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Let `x` and `v` be the original position and velocity, respectively. Your update loop should look like:

```
fg = -g * m
vn = normalize(v)
fd = -vn * 0.5f * p * Cd * A * v^2
a = (fg + fd)/m
v += a * dt
x += v * dt
```

where `g` is the gravitational magnitude, `m` is the mass, `fg` is the gravitational force, `fd` is the drag force and `a` is the acceleration. You can see that when you run this with your values `v` approaches your above calculation for terminal velocity.

Comment: `a = (fg + fd)/m`. The `-0.5f` already acts against the increase of velocity magnitude. The correct thing to do here is to actually use the velocity's vertical component's direction as in `fd = -0.5f * p * Cd * A * v^2 * v.y/fabs(v.y)` (for example). Otherwise, things are inconsistent with the general drag formulation. Apart from that, everything's fine.

Comment: You're forgetting that gravity pulls `y` down; my pseudo code is correct even if it doesn't look like an exact translation of the math. But you're right that this doesn't apply to the general case, only a falling object in the sense OP specified. In the general case we'd want to multiply `v` by `-v/||v||`, not just its y-component. It is really annoying that MathJax isn't supported.

Comment: yep, in this particular case, things should be ok. It works correctly only if your initial velocity is not pointing upwards (probably the OP's scenario)

Comment: I edited it to handle the general case.